# Removing Event Listener in Deactivate/Activate Event - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am using the code snippet from Flash Cs6 for my mobile Air app. How do I properly remove the listener? ( I get error 1120: Access of undefined property ocean_slider. ) with the following code. Thanks for your help.

```
/* Deactivate/Activate Event
Conserve CPU and battery life by suspending expensive processes, such as ENTER_FRAME     and TIMER events, when the application is not in focus.

Instructions:
1. Start timers and add event listeners in "fl_Activate".
2. Stop timers and remove event listeners in "fl_Deactivate".
*/

stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, fl_Activate);
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, fl_Deactivate);

function fl_Activate(event:Event):void
{
// Start timers and add event listeners here.

naturepage.sliders.ocean_slider.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ocean_slider);

function ocean_slider(e:Event):void
{
    ocean_transform.volume = (naturepage.sliders.ocean_slider.value/100);
    ocean_channel.soundTransform = ocean_transform;

}
}

function fl_Deactivate(event:Event):void
{
// Stop timers and remove event listeners here.
naturepage.sliders.ocean_slider.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ocean_slider);

}
```

OK. I just changed the code to the following but still have the problem. The listener is definitely getting added because the functions work in my app after publishing without the removeEventListener. But once I add the code to remove the listener, I get the error 1120 when I try to publish.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, fl_Activate);
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, fl_Deactivate);

function fl_Activate(event:Event):void
{

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
function myFunction(event:Event):void
{
ocean_transform.volume = (naturepage.sliders.ocean_slider.value/100);
ocean_channel.soundTransform = ocean_transform;
}
}

function fl_Deactivate(event:Event):void
{
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
}
```

Comment: a few things: this:naturepage.sliders.ocean_slider is not the best way.  You should not drill down into objects that way... your code for adding and removing is fine otherwise so my guess is that the object ocean_slider hasn't been created at the moment you are trying to add the listener to it... or it has been removed before you try to remove the listener.  I would move all this code into the sliders object so the listeners to ocean_slider are in scope with the ocean_slider and wait for a added to stage or creation complete event from ocean_slider, then add the enterframe listener to it

Comment: also don't name functions and objects the same name (ocean_slider) as this is a sure way to make mistakes and generate errors fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I think it's working now. I put the function all the way outside. Thanks for your help and responses.

```
function myFunction(event:Event):void
{
ocean_transform.volume = (naturepage.sliders.ocean_slider.value/100);
ocean_channel.soundTransform = ocean_transform;
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, fl_Activate);
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, fl_Deactivate);

function fl_Activate(event:Event):void
{
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
}

function fl_Deactivate(event:Event):void
{
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your brackets are off - is that the code you copied and pasted or what you're trying to run.  I'll edit the code after you confirm why the brackets are the way they are - specifically the 2 '}' in the ocean_slider function

Regardless, it means that ocean_slider isn't available and hasn't been added to the stage.  So if it has, you need to check to make sure you're not calling fl_Deactivate before things are ready.  And you also have a function call and stage item with the same name - ocean_slider - I'd change that and see if it works.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this yet?

Comment: @Jason Reeves I just edited my post. I am still learning how to use stackoverflow posting method. Pardon me if I am posting wrong.

Comment: That extra bracket closes the function fl_Activate(event:Event):void

Comment: the second set of code is better, but if you're still getting an error on the ocean_slider, you might want to make sure it's available in that class.  Is naturepage a property of the class this code is in?